# ¿Como puedo hacer girar los engranes?

Tags: c++, opengl

Necesito que los engranes giren, pero que lo hagan dos segundos después de que la compilación haya empezado, ya que por el momento si giran, pero lo hacen en seguida de que se compila el código, cosa que no quiero que sea de esa manera.

Había pensado en hacerlo con la función de `**setTimeout()**` pero no pude implementarlo de manera correcta, además de que no estoy seguro de que sea la función correcta para lo que quiero hacer.

En seguida les muestro el fragmento de código donde tengo las funciones para que gire el engrane y la velocidad que tendrá:

```
GLint t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
        if (t - T0 >= 5000) {
            GLfloat seconds = (t - T0) / 1000.0;
            GLfloat fps = Frames / seconds;
            printf("%d frames in %6.3f seconds = %6.3f FPS\n", Frames, seconds, fps);
            T0 = t;
            Frames = 0;
            if ((t >= 999.0 * autoexit) && (autoexit)) {
                cleanup();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}


static void
idle(void)
{
    static double t0 = -1.;
    double dt, t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    if (t0 < 0.0)
        t0 = t;
    dt = t - t0;
    t0 = t;

    angle += 00.0 * dt;  /* 70 degrees for second */
    angle = fmod(angle, 360.0); /* prevents eventual overflow */

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: En lugar de `t0 = -1` deberías usar `t0 = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` o dividido por 1000, como te resulte más conveniente. Aprovecho para sugerir que uses una librería de OpenGL más moderna. Por ejemplo SDL. O una librería de ventanas + una librería de OpenGL como GLFW y GLAD o GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea añade una pausa de 2 segundos:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
```

Para usarla debes añadir la siguiente cabecera:

```
#include <thread>
```